# Javascript reverse order date strings for use in table storage row keys

Tags: javascript, .net, date

When entries are returned from Azure table storage they are returned in lexicographical order based on the partition and row key. This can be used to avoid the use of an order by clause if you use reverse date order strings as a row key.

In .net in order to generate row keys to be used in this fashion the following code can be used:

```
var rowKey = String.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks );
```

Taking into account that millisecond is the smallest fraction of time in a javascript date what is the closest to an equivalent row key generation method?

Comment: So you want to convert the code above from .net to JS?

Comment: Yes, although their is no 1:1 translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` equivalent in JS is either:

```
(new Date()).getTime()
```

or (more simple):

```
Date.now()
```

`DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks` has no direct equivalent in JS. However, considering that the `Date object` range is `-100,000,000` days to `100,000,000` days relative to `01/01/1970 UTC` ([ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Date_Object)) it can be substituted with the following number:

```
100000000 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

So equivalent of the whole code is something like this:

```
var rowKey = (new Date(100000000 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - (new Date()).getTime())).toDateString();
```

Comment: Took your answer and changed it slightly: var currentTimeInMilliseconds = new Date()
            .getTime();
        var endOfTime = 100000000 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var rowKey = new Date(endOfTime - currentTimeInMilliseconds)
            .getTime()
            .toString();

Comment: String.Format("{0:D}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008"